# What's the point of leveling up in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Starting with beta 1.8 [prerelease](http://www.minecraftforum.net/news/215-18-updates-features-from-the-pre-release/), *Minecraft* players earn XP when they kill mobs!

What are the benefits of leveling up? More health? More damage? Larger inventory?

Comment: No use at all, yet. Great, huh? They get us all hyped about this update when all they do is add stuff that is useless until 1.9 or even later.

Comment: To be fair, when all the hype was going around initially 1.8 was intended to include both parts of the Adventure update. It wound up getting split into two parts later in the development process.

Comment: This system is actually awesome. A long more conventional levelling system like in WOW wouldnt fit minecraft, but one more "arcade style" would. It would actually mean something to have max stats (and even a few perks maybe?) for awhile until you died. It would keep up the riskiness.

Comment: Am I missing something because I'm pretty sure XP was in Minecraft long before 1.8.

Comment: @jacen.garriss: Notice the question date: this was at the time of *Beta 1.8*, not the current "Release" 1.8. The version number was reset when the official release happened (and when Beta started, for that matter).

Comment: @MichaelMadsen ah okay, Thanks for explaining. With the last release, I've been doing a lot of reading on it, and this article caught my eye.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Leveling up is currently used for 2 things:  Score, and enchanting.

### Score

[1 orb == 1 point](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/119024329550856192).  This score is displayed upon death (and possibly game completion.  I haven't gotten that far :P).

### Enchanting

As you collect orbs, your experience bar fills.  Everytime it gets completely full, it empties and you level up.  In this screenshot, the player is level 1.

[image]

Once you have an [enchantment table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_table), you can spend your experience on [enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantments).  These give one of your tools a special ability, such as a chance to not take any wear each time you use it, and additional harvesting speed.

Enchantments cost 1 to 3 levels depending on the type of enchantment, but you must be a certain level to access each one.  The highest tier appears to require you to be at or above level 30 to use, while still only costing 3 levels per enchantment.

<sub>One thing to note is that as of Release 1.8 enchantments also cost 1-3 pieces of Lapis Lazuli depending on the enchantment.</sub>

---

**BEFORE RELEASE VERSION 1.8**
Every enchantment has a cost paid in levels.  I.e. Level 2 enchantments cost 2 levels of experience.  In my screenshot above, the player can *only* buy level 1 enchantments, because he's only level 1.  By default, you can get up to level 5 enchantments with an enchantment table.  Placing bookshelves around your table will unlock higher level enchantments.

---

Your experience is reset when you die, although you do drop some experience orbs, which can be recovered like anything else you drop, assuming you find your death spot. The amount dropped is [7 times your level, up to 100, or enough to reach level 5](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Behavior).

Comment: You may want to add in new information about experience now also being used for Anvils.

Comment: The recent release of 1.8 changed the cost of enchantments to just a 1-3 levels, while still requiring a high overall level to access certain enchantments.

Comment: @cantido You're right. I just noticed that today, actually.

Comment: @John the Green 1.8 only came out a few days ago, I was just lucky enough to get a comment in first :)

Answer (score 10):

As of 1.9-pre4, leveling up provides skill levels that you can spend on [enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) for your items.

And as of 1.9-pre2, your total experience acts as a way to keep score: [one experience orb equals once point](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/119024329550856192). Combined with hardcore mode (which forces a player to delete their world upon death), it introduces elements to bring Minecraft more in line with the [Roguelike genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) of games—including Nethack, Angband, and Dungeons of Dredmor—that generally report your score upon game completion (read: death).

In the future, Mojang has talking about how leveling up will eventually provide a way to increase skills. What that means and how it's accomplished is entirely speculatory at this point: the only thing known for sure is that gaining enough experience orbs to "level up" [would award skill points](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_jJJTROkJ0#t=0m40s) that could be spent on "powering up abilities".  In terms of what powering up abilities means, [Notch said](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAMt1koF7Kw#t=1m42s):

> You could upgrade run speed, or like, maximum health, or uh, [inaudible]. Stuff like that.

It's unclear if this was an idea that's been replaced with enchanting or an alternative to enchanting that has yet to be implemented.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the behind the scenes video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PuGTIlJot0) for the trailer (starting around 1:35) there is currently no use of experience.

However, a future release will use experience (for some currently unknown purpose). It wasn't obvious whether this would carryover, so I'd say it's 50-50.

Answer (score 4):

As of Sep 10 '11, [it has no use at all](http://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftfaq/comments/k6pv9/q_what_is_experience_used_for_a_absolutely/). That's because Beta 1.8 is Adventure Update Part I. It will have a use in Beta 1.9, Adventure Update Part II, along with NPCs and more!

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

As of Minecraft release version 1.4.2, aka the "Pretty Scary Update", [Anvils](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil) were introduced, serving all sorts of different functions.

In accordance to your question, they serve two functions related to experience:

1: Repairing and Renaming Items

> Unlike crafting to repair items, Anvils can use materials to repair or
> combine two items. Anvils can both retain enchantments and expand on
> them. The player can also rename any item - not just tools or armor -
> using this method. This costs levels proportional to what is given.
> Simply renaming an item will cost 5 levels for a non-tool/armor item,
> whereas renaming and repairing an enchanted tool/armor is
> substantially more. On each use, anvils have a 12% chance to be
> damaged. On its last use, the GUI will close and the anvil will
> disappear, dropping the item on the ground.

2: Combining Enchantments

> Due to the lack of a level cap in creative mode, it is now possible to
> combine any two (or more) enchantments on two items. Owing to the
> anvils ability to add two enchantments together to make a better
> version (like two sharpness 2 swords can be combined to a sharpness 3
> sword), and the lack of a enchantment number cap (a knockback and
> looting sword can be combined with a fire and sharpness sword to make
> a knockback, looting, fire, and sharpness sword). Alone, each of these
> attributes is useful, but when combined together, it is possible (in
> creative) to make a Sharpness V, Fire Aspect II, Knockback II, Looting
> III Diamond Sword from a whole pile of lower enchantment tier diamond
> swords. (Ex: 16 Sharpness I swords, 4 Fire Aspect I swords, 4
> Knockback I swords, and 8 Looting I swords can be combined into a
> sword with the enchantments listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You need XP for enchanting or repairing tools on an enchantment table or an anvil.