# Minecraft: Experience Orbs in Beta 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of leveling up in minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/whats-the-point-of-leveling-up-in-minecraft)

Right now, Minecraft Beta 1.8 is out and I am wondering if they have added in anything that actually makes use of experience orbs?

Comment: But this question is different, im referring to the official minecraft not the pre-release

Comment: The original question doesn't refer to *only* the pre-release, it simply comments that XP became available *starting* in the pre-release.