# How do you spend experience in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of leveling up in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/whats-the-point-of-leveling-up-in-minecraft)

I assumed with 1.0 you got a way to spend your experience, but I noticed no way to do that.

Is that still work in progress, or I missed some kind of option somewhere?

Comment: dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30018/6028

Comment: I knew experience was meant to gain power ups and such, I asked *how* to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Minecraft 1.0 the new [enchanting system](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) was added. Once you have some diamond and obsidian (plus a book), you can craft an [enchantment table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_Table), which will allow you to put enchantments on your weapons, armor, and tools in exchange for experience.